# Are these asymptotic inequalities identical?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm struggling with asymptotic notation a little bit...

As $k$ becomes large, are these two inequalities actually the same?

$k \le n^{\log (n+1) - 1}(1+o(1))$ and $k \le n^{\log (n)}(1+o(1))$?

the first one is better, but it makes no difference since log(n) is asymptotic to log(n+1)-1?

Comment: What do you mean by "same"?

Comment: As in, are the inequalities equally as good or not?

Comment: Actually this one has an Answer; the other is a "repost" by the same user, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, but I considered that the other post incorporates feedback received here, and that the answer here was deemed insufficient. I may have been mistaken, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The expression on the LHS can be rewritten as 
$$
n^{\log (n+1) -1} = n^{\log n -1 + \log (1+\frac{1}{n})} \sim n^{\log n -1} n^{\frac{1}{n}} 
$$
The second term converges to 1 as $n \to \infty$, but the ratio $\frac{n^{\log n} }{n^{\log n -1}} = n^{\log n -\log n +1} = n$ which diverges to infinity.

Comment: Many thanks. So you're saying that the first inequality is better? Would you mind kindly explaining why  $n^{\log n -1 + \log (1+\frac{1}{n})} \sim n^{\log n -1} n^{\frac{1}{n}} 
$?

Comment: If the first function if $f_1(n)$ and the second $f_2(n)$, then $f_1(n) = o (f_2(n))$ or vice versa $f_2(n) = \omega(f_1(n))$.

Comment: I see, so the 1+o(1) stuff isn't relevant, really? The point is, since the $f_1(n)$ grows so much slower, it's a better inequality?

I guess this is kinda like comparing $n^{n}(1+o(1))$ with $n^{n-1}(1+o(1))$. Even though n and n-1 are basically the same, these two inequalities are not the same because we're talking about powers of n, right?

Comment: 'better' for what purpose?

Comment: I mean better in the sense that it's a stricter inequality for k?

Comment: It depends on what $k$ is. If it's some function $k(n)$, it may be $O(f_1)$ or $o(f_1)$, then it's automatically $o(1)$ because $f_1 = o(f_2)$

Comment: Sorry for not understanding this. I have two different inequalities. Inequality 1: $k \le n^{\log (n+1) - 1}(1+o(1))$ and  inequality 2: $k \le n^{\log (n)}(1+o(1))$? Is any inequality stronger than the other? Are you saying the answer depends on k?

Comment: I think k is just some number which grows however it likes, I don't think it's a function of n. Basically, if one wanted to prove one of these, you may as well prove the first inequality?

Comment: 'k is just some number which grows however it likes' sounds quite ridiculous. If it's it constant it's just $O(1)$ then. If it 'grows however it likes' asymptotic analysis is useless. To say something about the order of growth, it must be a function of $n$.

Comment: If your ultimate question is 'which of two functions grows slower', I already answered it.

Comment: Apologies Alex. In the 6th comment in this discussion did you mean "... it's automatically $o(f_2)$.." instead of "$o(1)$"?

Comment: yes, it should be $o(f_2)$.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid. You're right right. I appreciate you being patient with me.

Comment: no problem, you're welcome.

Comment: Sorry Alex, what if we assume n = o(k) ? Are the two inequalities equivalent in this case, then?

Comment: I'm sorry what you are saying makes absolutely no sense. What do you mean by $n = o(k)$?

Comment: I mean, what if we're saying "k is large" and all we know is that n=o(k)? I feel like I'm saying a lot of things that are stupid? What exactly am I saying that's wrong?